# How do I get a moving average?

Tags: java

I want to get a 5 day moving average from an array of numbers like so.

> Array of numbers: 11,12,13,14,15,16,17
>
> First day of 5-day moving average: (11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15) / 5 = 13
>
> Second day of  5-day moving average: (12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16) / 5 = 14
>
> Third day of 5-day moving average: (13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17) / 5 = 15

```
int[] arry = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
int sum = 0;
    
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    sum += arry[j];
    System.out.println(sum);
}
    
System.out.println();
int average = sum / 5;
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
System.out.println("Average: " + average);
```

Am able to get the first average but am lost on how to implement a loop to get the next set of averages?

Comment: hint: change the start / stop condition of your for loop dynamically so it moves.

Comment: I think you should figure this out for yourself, but here's a hint: After you've summed the first 5 numbers, you can get the next sum by taking the previous sum, subtracting one number, and adding one number.  Figure out what number you're supposed to subtract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following tested code (method from @ajb is more elegant, but I use the idea from @zapl for simplicity):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arry = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
    int size = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i + size <= arry.length ; i++)

        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < i + size; j++) {
            sum += arry[j];
            System.out.println(sum);
        }

        System.out.println();
        int average = sum / 5;
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Average: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: to make to more dynamic change the top forloop to this `for (int i = 0; i + 5 <= arry.length ; i++) `

Comment: @saikumarm Thanks a lot! I also added a variable `size` to replace the constant 5 :-)

Answer (score 0):

public class MovingAvarage {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] array = {1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5};

    double St = 0D;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        St = movingAvarage(St, array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(St);

}

private static double movingAvarage(double St, double Yt) {
    double alpha = 0.01, oneMinusAlpha = 0.99;
    if(St <= 0D) {
        St = Yt;
    } else {
        St = alpha*Yt + oneMinusAlpha*St;
    }
    return St;
}
```

}

Comment: I know this is just an example. But programmers that use variable names like St and Yt need to switch profession. I can't believe this is still a problem in 2019.
Please change the variable names so people can know what are they for (meaningful names).